# For loop with two variables in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am a bit new in JavaScript, trying to do the hardcoded part above in a more scalable way with the function below. The `'t' + i` functions well but do the same with the `.t + i`

```
function showInfo(results) {
  var data = results.data

  document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = [data[0].t1].join(', ')
  document.getElementById('t2').innerHTML = [data[0].t2].join(', ')
  document.getElementById('t3').innerHTML = [data[0].t3].join(', ')
  document.getElementById('t4').innerHTML = [data[0].t4].join(', ')

}
```

```
function showInfo(results) {
  var data = results.data

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('t' + i).innerHTML = [data[0].t + i].join(', ')
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an array and then doing a join of that single-element array?

Comment: `[data[0].t1].join(', ')` is the same as `data[0].t1.toString()`, hence it doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: `document.get(...).innerHTML  = data[0]['t'+i]`

Comment: @eloyra is makes a good point: `[data[0].t1].join(', ')` should just be `data[0].t1`.

Comment: Thank you all! `data[0]['t' + i]` works great with no join method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do instead:

```
function showInfo(results) {
  var data = results.data

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('t' + i).innerHTML = [data[0]['t' + i]].join(', ')
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect an the join is not necessary.

Comment: A solution which includes no hardcoding of the variables and is much more flexible would look like the following.

    `for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     Object.keys(data[i]).forEach(function(key) {
      document.getElementById(key).innerHTML(data[i][key]);
     });
    }`

In your code however it looks like you only ever want to target data[0], if that really is the case you do not need the for loop on it since you only want the first element.  like:

    `Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(function(key) {
  document.getElementById(key).innerHTML(data[0][key]);
 });`